Nest Thermostat wiring issue — not heating
We just moved in and tried to replace a Honeywell Thermostat with the Nest Learning Thermostat Gen 3.
Looks like the heat function is only blowing cool air, so we think we wired things incorrectly, but aren’t sure what to do to fix it. The A/C has been working fine and blows cool air.
Here is a link to the model of the system we see outside:
Rheem RP1424AJ1NA 2.0 Tons Classic 14 Seer Heat Pump 1 Stage R410A 208-230/60/1
Here’s the previous wiring with Honeywell:

Here’s how we tried to wire our Nest (wire labels added by us, so they may not be accurate): 
Update: We found out there are two sets of wires behind the plate; they are currently connected to the Nest as follows
Left set:

Blue - (pictured with exposed copper)
White - W2aux
Red - Rc
Green - G
Yellow - Y1

Right set:

Blue - (snipped/not connected)
White - C
Red - (snipped/not connected)
Green - Ob

Could someone please help us figure out which wires need to be swapped/moved to get the heat to work? Temps are starting to drop in our area, so we’re nervous to get heat soon! Thanks in advance!

Too bad you didn't take a direct picture of the Honeywell wiring...  Also, it would behoove you to tell us what HVAC equipment you have.  Gas furnace with A/C?  Heat pump?  Baseboards?  Boiler?  Something else?

Didn't know they were supposed to hear.

@Huesmann thanks for the tips, we’re beginners in the space and didn’t know what was important to mention. Just updated with more details. Looks like our system has a heat pump.

@JACK thanks for the typo call out, just fixed :)

@MicheT Do you have the Nest configured to run a heat pump? This sort of behavior would be consistent with a standard thermostat trying to run a heat pump system.  Also, what happens when you set the Nest for emergency heat?

You need to go in settings and change the setting for the reversing valve from O to B, Rheem valve must be energized for heat mode, most others must be energized for cooling, default is O setting

It's hard to be sure just by the pictures but I think you should move your wire from W2 to W1
Typically the heat is triggered by connecting Rh to W1. In your case your 24v supply is shared between both heating and cooling so it's on Rc (which is correct for the nest, but it was connected by a jumper in your old thermostat)
Fan is typically triggered by powering G, which is why that works. A/C is typically triggered on Y1. So I bet your A/C is working properly?
Your other wires are curious and you may need to provide more info about your setup to get it correct.
Also, blue wire is usually the C wire. Your picture makes it look like you have two different wire groups: one group of five conductors and one group of two conductors. Do you, perhaps, have a separate heating vs cooling system?

Thanks for the explanation! We are absolute beginners in this space so we’re not sure if they’re separate systems, but looks like it may be one through a heat pump(?) Here is the model — https://ebirdsall.com/rheem-rp1424aj1na-2-0-tons-classic-14-seer-heat-pump-1-stage-r410a-208-230-60-1.html?srsltid=AfmBOoqgxAefICTu-BQsISindTSjumouvt_saZHqIazr5TxUhptbOFQM

We found out there are two sets of wires, as you suspected! Thanks for the lead! Updated the post with the list of wires & where they’re currently connected. Do you have any suggestions to help us move forward? Anything helps, thanks!

The sets of wires look different to me, like clearly different looking insulation thickness. Are you comfortable looking at your heater and A/C units to see where the wires go on the other end and taking pictures?
